# Alias Definition on Mac

Tags: macos, zsh

I wanna open Mac apps from terminal, like “CotEditor .zpofile”.

So, I wrote .zprofile following,

```
alias -s app=open -a
regapps() {
  local app
  for app in $1/*.app(N); do; alias ${app:t:r:gs/ //}=${app:gs/ /\\ /}; done
  for app in $1/*/*.app(N); do; alias ${app:t:r:gs/ //}=${app:gs/ /\\ /}; done
}
regapps /Applications
regapps ~/Applications
regapps /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications
unset -f regapps
```

But, that defines like “alias CotEditor=/Applications/CotEditor.app”.

I guess, it should be “alias CotEditor='open $1 -a /Applications/CotEditor.app'”

However, I have no idea to deal two $1 in function regapps and $1 in alias...

One more,  I wanna define alias recursively in /Applications directory. (Now, alias wrote 2 lines, 2 Hierarchy)

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you should be defining functions instead of aliases. This is a recurring answer to alias-related questions.

Comment: Thanks! It may help me. I try to solve my issue again referring that topics.

Comment: You can use one `for` loop with `for app in $1/**/*.app(N); do`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the way, however it takes very long time (doesn't end even wait much). I guess, loop also runs in *.app/ as directory.